# Best Java lib for programmatically converting a HTML page to an Image/PDF

Tags: java, flying-saucer, html-to-pdf, html-to-jpeg

I am looking for the best Java lib which I can pass in a URL and have it create an image of what the web page looks like as it would in a browser. I tried out [flyingsaucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/)  however it seems like almost every web page breaks it -- it wont even render www.google.com or yahoo.com -- the only site i could get it to render is www.w3c.org!

Thoughts on a better tool to use, or possibly allow flying saucer to be more lax in the xhtml is accepts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flying Saucer fails on many pages since it only allows xhtml (see manual).

But you can use some html libs to "clean" your input an then use FS.

**Webesite -> "Cleaner" -> Flying Saucer**

Some good and free libs are:

1. [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) (personal recommendation)
2. [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/)
3. [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) (sometimes more strict than needed)
4. [Jericho HTML](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try itext.jar

download it from http://itextpdf.com/download.php

Answer (score 0):

about html crawling:

use URL from java library. there are tons of examples about this.

about PDF converting:

If you are using Spring framework, you can use AbstractPdfView class via iText api. [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-pdf-file-via-abstractpdfview/) is my favorite example. I think you can easily make use of it.

about image converting:

I recommend this one: http://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/

total:

read html by URL → convert it via iText or java-html2image. I strongly recommend you to do it yourself, not leave it to a certain library.